# logical problem for finding the probability

Tags: logic, puzzle

hi to all
 I want to know how to find the solution for this problem. consider in a Jar there are 10 papers numbered 1 to 10. we have to take 2 papers from that. what is the probability that 2 numbers are consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a probability to choose one of 9 consecutive pairs from C(10, 2) possible pairs. Thus its 9 / (10*9 / 2) = 1 /5

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting 2-8 is 8/10. Once we have a given number in that range, the probability of getting one of the two adjacent numbers is 2/9. 8/10 * 2/9 = 16/90.

The probability of getting either a 1 or a 10 is 2/10. If we have one of those two endpoint numbers, the probability of getting the one adjacent number is 1/9. 2/10 * 1/9 = 2/90.

Adding these together, we have a total probability of 18/90 or 1/5.

Answer (score 0):

Your first choice has ten possible numbers.  8 of those 10 will have two consecutive numbers, while the other two only have 1.  Your second choice will be out of nine numbers.  So

(8/10 * 2/9) + (2/10 * 1/9) = 9/45 = 1/5